# Using AutoMapper, how do I set a property based on another table's property?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am having two tables.

**Request table**
...
UserId
RequesterId
..

**User table**
Id
Name
..

I need to map this request model into a ViewModel, adding a "User" and "Requester" string property, filled with the corresponding User's names, searched by their ID. RequesterId is the user's ID who submitted the request, UserId is the user's ID who is the request for.

**ListRequestViewModel**
..
Username
Requestername
..

So far, this is my mapper class code:

```
public class MapperProfile : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public MapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<Request, ListRequestViewModel>().ForMember(x => x.Requester, opts => opts.MapFrom(u => u.Requester.Name))
                .ForMember(x => x.RequestedUser, opts => opts.MapFrom(u => u.User.Name));
        }
    }
```

Of course, this will not work, because I need to find the User, that has the same Id, like the Request's UserId, or RequesterId.

How do I find the users in CreateMap?

Comment: Please include the code of all models mentioned in your question allowing us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: I am not sure if the table's other columns are relevant here. I just want to connect the request table to the user table, and get a user's name by its Id.

Comment: tldr: How do I map this into the corresponding fields?
SELECT User.Name FROM User WHERE Request.UserId = User.Id;